# Modify Bitrate from userspace CAN0

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, archlinux

can some one help me in modifying the bitrate from userspace.

root@CMS5 /sys/devices/platform/FlexCAN.1$ cat bitrate
500000

i want to set this to 250 kbps.
is it possible from userspace ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing `250000` to `/sys/device/platform/FlexCAN` but I don't see where in the driver that is handled.  (But, for that matter, I don't see where it outputs its current rate either.)

Is there reason to believe that the bitrate *can* be modified?  Usually, you want network device to work as fast as they can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ip command to configurate CAN interface.
ip link set can0 type can bitrate 250000

You can get more information follow command:
root@PC:/sys/devices/platform# ip link set can0 type can help
Usage: ip link set DEVICE type can
        [ bitrate BITRATE [ sample-point SAMPLE-POINT] ] | 
        [ tq TQ prop-seg PROP_SEG phase-seg1 PHASE-SEG1
          phase-seg2 PHASE-SEG2 [ sjw SJW ] ]

```
    [ loopback { on | off } ]
    [ listen-only { on | off } ]
    [ triple-sampling { on | off } ]
    [ one-shot { on | off } ]
    [ berr-reporting { on | off } ]

    [ restart-ms TIME-MS ]
    [ restart ]

    Where: BITRATE       := { 1..1000000 }
           SAMPLE-POINT  := { 0.000..0.999 }
           TQ            := { NUMBER }
           PROP-SEG      := { 1..8 }
           PHASE-SEG1    := { 1..8 }
           PHASE-SEG2    := { 1..8 }
           SJW           := { 1..4 }
           RESTART-MS    := { 0 | NUMBER }
```